# unrecognized selector sent to instance, on a different class

Tags: ios, swift, exception, selector

In an iOS Swift app I have this crash:

```
-[UIText localSettings]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1688aa90
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIText localSettings]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1688aa90'
```

Indeed `UIText` does not have any `localSettings` selector. Here `localSettings` is a method of mine, for a different class.
I have somewhere in my code a line like this:

```
myButton!.addTarget(self, action: Selector("localSettings"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

But for some unknow reason, after a short while, myButton cease to work and I get the above crash.
I have read that it could be because the button is missing and the next responder would look for a `localSettings` of its own.

Though I take care that the button is present, at this point I have not solved the problem. Any tip on how to locate the source of the issue or how to fix it would be more than welcome.

Comment: What is `myButton` ? How did you declare and initialize it ?

Comment: Declaration is:   var myButton: UIButton?

Initialization is: myButton = settingButton()

Where settingButton is defined as:

func settingButton() -> UIButton {
        return appSettingButton!
    }

Comment: From which class you are using the above mentioned code ?

Comment: post this action "localSettings" too

Comment: Thanks but I just solved the issue, as often I was not looking exactly at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the

```
myButton!.addTarget(self, action: Selector("localSettings:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

and for your function use

```
func localSettings(aButton: UIButton) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the tip. But it doesn't change anything, still crashing.